# What is the probability that the five selected cards include exactly three hearts? four aces? no hearts?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Five cards are selected with replacement from a standard pack of $52$ playing cards. What is the probability that the selected cards include:

$ 1.~$ Exactly three hearts 
$ 2.~$ Four aces
$ 3.~$ No hearts?

In relation to the first part, I simply found $(13)^3$ multiplied by $(39)^2$, and then divided by $(52)^5$. This gives $9$ over $1024$. The answer however is $2717 $ over $33320~ ($part $1)$. For parts $2$ and $3$ the answers are $1$ over $54145$, and $2109$ over $9520$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

(1) P(E)=${5 \choose 3}\frac{(13)^3(39)^2}{52^5}$ 
$$ p(E)=10.\frac{9}{4^5}$$
(2) p(E) = 5$ \frac{12}{13^5}$
$$. $$
(3)p(E)=$\frac{3^5}{4^5}$

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions when the person who posted the question has not shown he or she has attempted the problem.

Comment: thanks , I will take care of the same.